# Jquery nestedSortable: how fire custom events?

Tags: jquery

This is the plugin: https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable

I have a basic list:

```
<ol class="sortable">
    <li><div>Centri estetici</div></li>
    <li><div>Parrucchieri</div></li>
    <li><div>Ristoranti</div></li>
    <li>
        <div>Tempo libero</div>
        <ol>
            <li><div>Parchi a tema</div></li>
            <li><div>Zoo</div></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><div>Agriturismi</div></li>
</ol>
```

It works, but I cannot / I don't know how fire the event that item is placed. Basically, after the drag and drop, I want to call the toArray method and update the database.

I did try this:

```
var ns = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    //maxLevels: 4,
    isTree: true,
    expandOnHover: 700,
    startCollapsed: false
});

$('ol.sortable li').on('nestedSortable.change', function(event) {
    alert('change');
});

$('ol.sortable li').on('nestedSortable.sort', function(event) {
    alert('sort');
});

$('ol.sortable li').on('nestedSortable.relocate', function(event) {
    alert('relocate');
});
```

But I don't get the alert neither for relocate, not for sort, not for change.

I did try also to remove the prefix "nestedSortable" after the "on" but unable to get anything (only the "change" alert at page load).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be add the event directly inside controller.

https://jsfiddle.net/107bx70o/

```
var ns = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    //maxLevels: 4,
    isTree: true,
    expandOnHover: 700,
    startCollapsed: false,
    change: function(){
        console.log('change');
    },
    sort: function(){
        console.log('sort');
    },
    relocate: function(){
        console.log('relocate');
    }
});
```